# How to query "where" something equals something

Tags: yii2

Right so at the minute my query looks like this:

```
$subcategory = Subcategory::find()->asArray()->all();
```

this basically grabs all the data from my subcategory table and stores it into $subcategory.

However i want to find specific data. For example in my subcategory table i have a column called subcategory_id.

Now i want to pull back all the subcategories where subcategory_id = $firstcategory(This will be a number)

Im guessing that it is something like this, however it is not working. Any ideas on how to do this query?

```
$subcategory = Subcategory::find()->asArray()->all()->where('subcategory_id' 
 == $firstcategory);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to guess, just read the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail). Here is one of the ways to do it:

```
$subcategory = Subcategory::find()
    ->where(['subcategory_id' => $firstcategory]);
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Note that order of using `all()` is crucial, once it's called you get the array of results and you can not modify query anymore.

Comment: ive literally just resolved this by putting   

$subcategory = Subcategory::findAll(['parent_id' => $firstcategory]);

Comment: I don't know what else you need, According to your current question formulation, I gave you the answer exactly how to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, you can also get the data like that, but you are using `asArray()` in your question. There is no way to add that in this case because `findAll()` returns result immediately after it's called.